# How to save a file that is captured by PHP-MIME-MAIL-PARSE and read fopen by command? LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I set up a procmail that receives emails and by command Laravel captures it, the issue is that when capturing and extracting the text I need to save a copy inside laravel as a backup.

The problem is that I don't want to save the captured file. Attached code.

```
Command File

$parser = new Parser();
//I capture the mail
$doc = $parser->setStream(fopen("php://stdin", "r"));

//Try save file
$nameFile = $website->hostnames->implode('fqdn') .'_'. time();
$url = Storage::disk('tenancy')->putFileAs($website->id,$doc,$nameFile);
```

I clarify that we will only receive from the email a simple text template, no attachments will be sent. Then we parse that email and extract the corresponding text.

For that reason I would like to save a copy of what it takes since later with an logrotative it will be maintained or I only do it with logrotative.

Comment: Dont understand. You want to save the text but not the attachments?

Comment: @FelipeZúñigaNúñez Exactly, only the text or the complete email as if it were an example of an email .eml file, because we are only going to receive pure text and then we parse the email to extract the data from the template of that email.

Because later on the server will create an logrotative to keep those files for 30 days and then delete them and continue with the data capture through the mails that we receive.